# Printing list with set width in python

Tags: python, parsing, list

quick and hopefully easy question.

Let's say I have a variable that is equal to a numerical width value

i.e.: size_x = 50

I want to print the list, wrapping to a width of 50 elements. How do I do this?

Comment: I don't get it... you want to check if your list contains only lines of length 50?

Comment: very confusing question... can you give us some examples of what's in your list and what the desired output should be?

Comment: sorry, i edited to hopefully make some more sense. if not I'll try to explain better next time

Comment: I think he means something like `for i in list: print "%*s"&(size_x, i);` or something like that... a fixed width print?

Comment: the new list has no new lines or anything, it is just very very long, so when it is printed out on the screen it needs to start a new line once that row reaches a length of 50 and continue to print out until the end.

Comment: fixed - should be understandable now

Comment: @tekknolagi yes thats kindof what I am talking about. at least the phrase fixed-width print sounds right. Say I have a list that is 850 elements long, I need it to print 50 and then start a new line and continue to print like that until the whole list has been iterated over

Comment: roboman, 50 elements or 50 characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**guess 1**: print lines containing only size_x elements of the original list

```
for i in range(len(mylist)/size_x):
    print(mylist[i*size_x:(i+1)*size_x])
```

**guess 2**:  a new list of which the elements are strings of only size_x characters

```
newlist = []
for i in range(len(mylist)/size_x):
    newlist.append(''.join(mylist[i*size_x:(i+1)*size_x]))
```

printing newlist of 'guess 2' all at once to the screen is quicker than first guess:

`print('\n'.join(newlist))`

(also note that prior to python 3, `xrange()` can be used instead of `range()`, which generates i-values 'on the go' instead of creating a whole list of indices first. Python 3 does this standard with `range()`)

**example**

```
mylist = list('hello this is supposed to be a long line')
size_x=5
for i in range(len(mylist)/size_x):
    print(mylist[i*size_x:(i+1)*size_x])

['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
[' ', 't', 'h', 'i', 's']
[' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 's']
['u', 'p', 'p', 'o', 's']
['e', 'd', ' ', 't', 'o']
[' ', 'b', 'e', ' ', 'a']
[' ', 'l', 'o', 'n', 'g']
[' ', 'l', 'i', 'n', 'e']

newlist = []
for i in range(len(mylist)/size_x):
    newlist.append(''.join(mylist[i*size_x:(i+1)*size_x]))
print('\n'.join(newlist))

hello
 this
 is s
uppos
ed to
 be a
 long
 line
```

Comment: if he wants to print 50 elements, this will work. 50 characters? no. not sure which he wants

Comment: you need to have a `range()` in there - int is not iterable

Comment: sorry,I edited after you posted your comment... We keep guessing what he wants. My latest guess is he wants to end up with a `newlist`of which the elements are strings of only size_x characters

Comment: range() is the replacement for xrange() in python3

Comment: and I need 50 elements per line in the list when it is printed out.

Comment: after trying guess1 in my code i get: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: @roboman - you seem to have declared `size_x` as `size_x = "50"`. change this to `50` please. an int.